# forecast throws error K must be not be greater than period/2

Tags: r

I issue the following commands:

```
ops <- read.csv("ops.csv")
ops.ts <- ts(ops, frequency=12, start=c(2014,1))
ops.fc <- forecast(ops.ts)
```

forecast() then throws the following error:

```
Error in ...fourier(x, K, 1:length(x)) : 
  K must be not be greater than period/2
```

The data from the csv looks like this according to summary(ops):

```
1  10
2   3
3   7
4   4
5   2
6  20
7  13
8   9
9   8
10  7
11  6
12 11
13  7
```

R is up to date, Forecast is installed via CRAN.

I appreciate any advice especially because I am quiet new to R.

Comment: Do you want to use the 13th month (January 2015) or not ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is self-explanatory.

You have 13 elements in your dataset so when you do:

```
ops.ts <- ts(ops, frequency = 12, start=c(2014, 1))
```

You get (notice the 2015 value here):

```
#> ops.ts
#     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
#2014  10   3   7   4   2  20  13   9   8   7   6  11
#2015   7
```

I'm guessing you only want to use the first 12 months and then use `forecast()` ? If that is the case you can do either:

```
ops.ts <- ts(ops, frequency = 12, start = 2014, end = c(2015, 0))
ops.fc <- forecast(ops.ts)
```

or

```
ops <- ops[1:12, ]
ops.ts <- ts(ops, frequency = 12, start = 2014)
ops.fc <- forecast(ops.ts)
```